# CMake: "Imported target <target> includes non-existent path"

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm trying to use the [Alembic](https://github.com/alembic/alembic) framework, and have made the following CMakeFile

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(alembic-testing LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Alembic REQUIRED CONFIG)
add_executable(alembic-testing main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(alembic-testing Alembic::Alembic)
```

This fails on the cmake step fails

```
$ mkdir build && cd build

$ which cmake
/mingw64/bin/cmake

$ cmake -G"MSYS Makefiles" ..
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 10.1.0
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/g++.exe - works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
CMake Error in CMakeLists.txt:
  Imported target "Alembic::Alembic" includes non-existent path

    "/mingw64/include/OpenEXR"

  in its INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES.  Possible reasons include:

  * The path was deleted, renamed, or moved to another location.

  * An install or uninstall procedure did not complete successfully.

  * The installation package was faulty and references files it does not
  provide.
```

But the directory `/mingw64/include/OpenEXR` *does* exist

```
$ [ -d "/mingw64/include/OpenEXR" ] && echo "YES"
YES
```

I've tried un-setting the `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES`

```
set_target_properties(Alembic::Alembic PROPERTIES
  INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES ""
)
```

but that leads to issues with missing includes during compilation.

**EDIT**: if I do the above and add

```
target_include_directories(alembic-testing PUBLIC "/mingw64/include/OpenEXR")
```

It compiles just fine... I'll have to look into the difference between these two settings.

I'm on Windows 10 (build 18363) using CMake (version 3.17.3) via MSYS2.

Alembic is installed via MSYS2: https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-alembic

Comment: Do you use the MSYS2 CMake package or the Windows CMake package? You should use the MSYS2 one.

Comment: I use the MSYS2/mingw64 cmake (`where cmake` returns `/mingw64/bin/cmake`).

Comment: If I unset `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` and add `target_include_directories(alembic-testing PUBLIC "/mingw64/include/OpenEXR")` it compiles fine. I'm guessing `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` works in a different way than `target_include_directories`..?

Comment: Looks like the Alembic `*config.cmake` script is wrong.  See similar issue https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5660

Comment: That fixed the problem. Thanks! I've opened an issue https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/6651. Feel free to answer this question with the solution, and I'll mark it as solved.